# How can i create a new column count in SQL table where count=1 if hours column >=6 else count=0

Tags: sql

I aim to first achieve this

| id | employee | Datelog | TimeIn | TimeOut | Hours | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Two | 2022-08-10 | 09:00:00 | 16:00:00 | 07:00:00 | 1 |
| 4 | Two | 2022-08-09 | 09:00:00 | 16:00:00 | 07:00:00 | 1 |
| 3 | Two | 2022-08-08 | 09:00:00 | 16:00:00 | 07:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | One | 2022-08-05 | 09:00:00 | 16:00:00 | 07:00:00 | 1 |
| 1 | Two | 2022-08-04 | 09:00:00 | 10:00:00 | 01:00:00 | 0 |

and now my main objective here is to give a bonus of 2k to employees whose Totalcount per month >=3.

| employee | Month | TotalCount | Bonus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Two | August | 3 | 2000 |
| One | August | 1 | 0 |

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server.   Please tag the appropriate database.

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work? What about the research you performed to help you solve the problem didn't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer using `Postgres`. It's pretty much generic other than extracting the month out of `datelog` that might have a slightly different syntax.

```
select   employee
        ,max(date_part('month', datelog ))
        ,count(*)
        ,case when count(*) >= 3 then 2000 else 0 end as bonus
from     t
where    hours >= time '06:00:00'
group by employee
```

| employee | max | count | bonus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Two | 8 | 3 | 2000 |
| One | 8 | 1 | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GwoIhqZi)